# Getting 400 Bad Request despite catching the err in angular2+

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I have designed a login page where login is successful when i put a correct login and password and Login doesn't happen when I put an incorrect username or password which is correct. However, I get this error:

> POST http://localhost:3003/login/authenticate 400 (Bad Request)
>
> ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://localhost:3003/login/authenticate", ok: false, …}

Everything works properly however, I get the error in the console. Like this:

[image: dom]

I want the 400 bad request error to not appear in the console. How to do that?

**login.component.ts**

```
login(data) {

    console.log("Inside Login");

    this.authenticateObj = {
      username: data.username,
      password: data.password
    }


    this.http.post("http://localhost:3003/login/authenticate", 
      this.authenticateObj)
      .map(Response => Response)
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("err =", err)
         alert('Login Failed. Username or Password 
       is incorrect');
          return Observable.throw(err);
      })
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        console.log("Inside login authenticate subscribe");

        this.info = res;
        if (this.info.message == 'Login Successful.') {


          console.log("test after login = ", this.info);


          if (localStorage.getItem('username') && 
          localStorage.getItem('token')) {
             alert('Login Successful');
            this.router.navigate(['/file-upload/wsdl']);
          } else {
            this.notification.Error('Unauthorized');
          }
        }
        if (this.info.message == 'error') {
          alert('Login Failed');
        }
        else if (this.info.status == 400) {
          alert('Login Failed');
        }
      })


  }
```

**login.controller.js**

```
function authenticateUser(req, res, next) {

console.log("Inside authenticateUser = ", req.body)

    LoginService.authenticate(req,req.body)
        .then(function (token) {

            if (token) {
                res.setHeader("authorization",token.token);
                res.send({
                  message: 'Login Successful.',   

                    response: token
                });
            } else if(res.message == 'Username or Password is 
            incorrect'){ 

                res.status(401).send({
                    message: 'Unauthorized. '
                });
            }
            else { 
                console.log("inside controller, else res.status-400");  
                res.status(400).send({
                    message: 'Username or password is incorrect'
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("inside controller, catch res.status 400")
            // res.status(400).send(err);

            res.status(400).send({
                message: 'Username or password is incorrect'
            });

        });
}
```

Comment: You cannot stop the HTTP errors from displaying in console.The best you can do in your browser is filter the logged message to custom level.Alternatively you can do full page reload after the failed login attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to handle errors from server properly, you have to catch them in the `subcribe()` method of the `Observable` returned by `http.post` from Rxjs:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:3003/login/authenticate", this.authenticateObj)
    .subscribe(
        (res: Response) => {
            // code when no error...
        }, 
        err => {
            // error handling...
        },
        () => {
            // finally...
        }
    );
```

Comment: thanks veben. but i still get -->OPTIONS http://localhost:3003/login/authenticate 0 ()  --> in color red in the console. Any work around ?

Answer (score 2):

IMO Bad request is an incorrect response by your server for incorrect username/password combination. You can return a "401" or a "200" itself depending on your requirement.

Now if you want the error not to appear in the console then add an error callback in your `subscribe()`.

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:3003/login/authenticate", this.authenticateObj)
    ...
    // rest of the code
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
       // your code
    }, (error) => {
        // handle the error here, show some alerts, warnings, etc
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks xyz. I still get --> OPTIONS http://localhost:3003/login/authenticate 0 ()  -> in color red in console.

Comment: @Techdive: Nope, no workaround for that. That red color indicates the status of the network request, not an error thrown by the APP. That red color is desired because your server wants that. If you don't want that red msg then you will have to consider that request as a success and send the response with 2XX series code (Not recommended, but yeah depends on your requirement)